# Python: Check if Azure queue storage exists

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage-queues

I want to get queue storage and create if it not exist. For most similar scenario I was using `exists()` method but when I look at python documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python) I can not see any method that can solve this problem
Here is my code:

```py
def send_to_queue(CONN_STR, queue_name, mess):
    service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONN_STR)
    queue = service_client.get_queue_client(queue_name)
    if not queue.exists():
        queue.create_queue()
    queue.send_message(mess)
```

What can I use in my if statement to solve this?

Comment: I think this is the best option for now. I find it odd that only Python SDK does not have `create_if_not_exists` kind of functionality (all other SDKs have this). I have raised a feature request here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21044. Please add your comments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try` `except` instead. As per the docs [*`create_queue`* creates a new queue in the storage account. If a queue with the same name already exists, the operation fails with a *`ResourceExistsError`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python#create-queue---kwargs-).

```
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError

def send_to_queue(CONN_STR, queue_name, mess):
    service_client = QueueServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONN_STR)
    queue = service_client.get_queue_client(queue_name)
    try:
        queue.create_queue()
    except ResourceExistsError:
        # Resource exists
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks :D 
I was thinking about this idea but I didn't know how to import `ResourceExistsError`