# Azure Storage (classic) vs Azure Storage (V2) code not working for V2 storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role running and checking to see if data exists in a storage hosted on Azure. My code works when I use the connection string for a classic type of storage, but when I connect to my V2 Azure storage, it throws this exception.

"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

```
while (true) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
      if (queue.Exists()) // The exception is throw here. 
      {
         try
         {
            CloudQueueMessage msg = await queue.GetMessageAsync();
            if (msg != null)
            {
              //data manipulation code...
            }
         }
   
      }
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to use a V2 storage instead of classic as classic is now depreciated on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the few workaround may solved the above issue,

*The authorization information required for your application to access data in an Azure Storage account at runtime using Shared Key authorzation is contained in a **`connection string`**. As illustrated below, you can configure connection strings*.

- Establish a connection with the Azurite storage emulator.
- In Azure, you can access a storage account.
- Access specified resources in Azure via a shared access signature (SAS).

*Please make sure to provide the correct connection string of storage account which you want to get/read the data.*

For more information,please refer to this [**`MS DOC|Configure Azure Storage connection strings`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string)

Also based on this [***MICRSOFT DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

---

> If you attempt to create a container or blob with a name that violates
> naming rules, the request will fail with status code 400 (Bad
> Request).

---

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69449622/python-check-if-azure-queue-storage-exists).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out that the reason was due to the Minimum TLS was at 1.2 whereas it had to be at 1.1 Microsoft Azure Storage.

Comment: Glad that your issue got resolved by changing the TLS to 1.1